# Jquery: ajaxSend & ajaxStop events not working?

Tags: ajax, events, jquery

can't seem to get the ajaxSend and Stop to work... These are global variables no? .. but I should be able to use like this... but I never get an alert??

I wanted to use these events to display an ajax animation.. although in my code I wish to position the ajax animation depending on what I am doing a what element it is.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MyService.aspx/TestMe",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    ajaxSend: function (r, s) {
        alert('i am starting');
    }
    ,
    ajaxStop: function (r, s) {
        alert('i am stopping');
    }
    ,
    success: function (msg) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you don't use this functionality properly. ajaxStop, ajaxComplete and etc. is not a parameters of $.ajax function. Let say you have an ajax icon which you want to remove on request completion.

```
 $("#ajax_icon").ajaxStop(function(){
   $(this).hide();
 });
```

You have a good reference [here](http://api.jquery.com)

PS. With other function is the same.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.8 you should only attach those handlers to the document: `$(document).ajaxStop(function () { })`

Answer (score 3):

Those are globals, and the way I typically see them assigned is:

```
$('element').ajaxStart(function() {
 ... do something ...
}
```

Assigning them to a specific ajax request, I'm not sure if that will do what you want it to do.

Comment: For posterity, it does work.